# Android Maven archtype project layout doesn't show correct on ADT Graphical Editor

Tags: android, maven, adt, maven-archetype, android-maven-plugin

I created an Android-Maven archetype project using command line (http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes).

When I imported this project to ADT (so that I can take some advantage of the graphical editor), I found the graphical editor doesn't show the view correctly.

For the auto generated activity_main.xml under res/layout, it doesn't displaying the expected layout. Instead, it complains:

```
No resources match the configuration

, , Locale Language ___Region __, Left To Right, sw320dp, w320dp, h533dp, Normal Screen, Long screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Exposed navigation, Trackball navigation, Screen resolution 800x480, API Level 18

Change the configuration or create:

res/layout-ldltr-sw320dp-w320dp-h533dp-normal-long-port-notnight-hdpi-finger-keyssoft-nokeys-navexposed-trackball-800x480-v18/activity_main.xml

You can also click the 'Create New...' item in the configuration dropdown menu above.
```

Screen shot as below:

[image]

Here is the project directory:
[image]

This Activity_Main.xml is pretty straight forward as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Project.properties file:

```
# Project target.
target=android-16
```

And AndroidManifest is also simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.hizz.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0-SNAPSHOT" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I am not sure what I should do to make it show on the graphical editor.

Please help out, and let me know if you need any extra information.

Comment: I just installed the same project from maven, and everything works fine. It should simply find the default implementation for activity_main.xml in the layout/ folder. Can you check if you have the latest version of the Android Development Tools (in Eclipse go to `Help -> Check for updates`).

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and restart eclipse, it always happens to me